# Gradient drawn into a clipped context does not appear on simulators for iPhone 6 plus, 6s plus and 7 plus ONLY

Tags: ios-simulator, uibezierpath, iphone-6-plus

I have a custom UIView using draw rect in the typical way to draw. UIBezierPaths are created, used to clip/draw a gradient, and then code moves on to do more of the same.

While sublayers to this view DO show up, gradients drawn into the clipped context don't show up, but the problem is only in those 3 simulators. The gradients show up in all of the other simulators.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to ask/answer this as it is the kind of thing that could take a long time to track down:

It turns out, just one of the UIBezierPaths was imperfect. I had edited the numbers by hand for that path. Once that imperfect path was involved, ALL of the gradients stopped working. Without that path, all was well.

For those who might be interested, here is the problematic path:

```
let groundPath = UIBezierPath()
groundPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 5))
groundPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 7700, y: 5))
groundPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 8096, y: 135), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 8052, y: 5), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 8096, y: 50))
groundPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 135))
groundPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 5))
groundPath.close()
return groundPath
```

I had edited the control points by hand, and it looked how I wanted, but something did not sit well with the plus iPhones.